# Is the target assumed to be a noisy version of the output of the model in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistical-ai

I wonder if the following equation (you can find it in almost every ML book) refers to a general assumption that we make when using machine learning:

$$y = f(x)+\epsilon,$$

where $y$ is our output, $f$ is e.g. a neural network and $\epsilon$ is an independent noise term.

Does this mean that we assume the $y$'s contained in our training data set come from a noised version of our network output?

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. The neural network (or whatever else you use) is a *model* of what you are trying to do, and usually models are not able to perfectly model reality, as it is too complex. A noise term is generally used to represent that, ie the imperfection of the model's relationship with the actual world.

Answer (score 1):

That equation is just an assumption that we make about the relationship between a *response variable* (aka [*dependent variable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables#Statistics_synonyms)) $y$ and a *predictor* (aka [*independent variable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables#Statistics_synonyms)) $x$, i.e. the response variable (target) is an **unknown** function $f$ of the predictor $x$ plus some noise $\epsilon$ due to e.g. measurement errors (caused e.g. by damaged sensors). So, if you have a dataset $D = \{(y_i, x_i)\}_{i=1}^N$, you assume that $y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon, \forall i$. The goal (in supervised learning) is then to **estimate** $f$ with e.g. a neural network $\hat{f}_\theta$, so the goal is to find a function $\hat{f}_\theta$ such that $\hat{f}_\theta(x_i) = y_i$, so, in practice, you often ignore $\epsilon$ because that is associated with irreducible errors.

You can find that equation on page 16 of the book [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/). There you will also find more info about the goal of (statistical) supervised learning and why $\epsilon$ is irreducible.

So, the answer to your question is **no**, given that $f$ there is not the neural network but an unknown function. If your neural network $\hat{f}$ was equal to $f$, then, yes, but, of course, in practice, this will almost never be the case.

Comment: thanks for answering! How does this apply to the Kalman Filter where we say that $y = Hx + r$, where r is the measurement noise. If there is no measurement noise, then the observations can be fully derived from the state?

Comment: @m_3464gh I'm not currently familiar with the details of the Kalman filter, so I can't answer your question. I was about to suggest you to ask a separate question, but you have already done that [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27100/2444).